# How to search for similarities in an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an arrayList of String which I would like to display in a Spinner or drop down menu, but mostly what happens is I have Strings repeating, what I want to do is to search through the arrayList for similarities, if its found a string for example "Hello World" occurs 7 times in the arrayList, remove the the other 6 and assign 7 to it to show that it occurred 7 times, so my new String will be "Hello world (7)", could anyone help me on how I can implement this in my code below:

```
for(int i = 0; i < timesCalleddb.getAllTimesCalled(missedCall.getNumber()).size(); i++)
    {

        if(timesCalleddb.getAllTimesCalled(missedCall.getNumber()).get(i) ==
                timesCalleddb.getAllTimesCalled(missedCall.getNumber()).get(i+1))
        {
           //where am guessing the implementation my problem should be
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using map data structure, since you have to store the counter, otherwise, hash set would be perfect:

```
ArrayList<String> strs = ...;

HashMap<String, Integer> counter = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for(String s : strs) {
    counter.put(s, counter.get(s) == null ? 1 : counter.get(s) + 1);
}

for(String s : counter.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(s + " (" + counter.get(s) + ")");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

1. Iterate over the `List` and make a `HashMap<String, Integer>` indicating how many times each `String` appears.
2. Remove duplicates from the `List` using `list = new ArrayList<String>(new LinkedHashSet<String>(list));`. Using a `LinkedHashSet` means that the order is kept.
3. Build up a new `List` by iterating over the `List` and adding either `string` or `string + " (" + map.get(string) + ")"` depending on whether `map.get(string)` is `1` or more than `1`.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the repeated `String` from a `List`, use the following:

```
List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
// Your elements must be added to the arrayList, before progressing to the next step.
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
set.addAll(arrayList );

// Code for getting count of each String
int count = 0;
List<Integer> arrayListCount = new ArrayList<>();
for (Iterator<String> it = set.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    String str = it.next();
    arrayListCount.add(count , 0);
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++){
        String s = arrayList.get(i);
        if (str.equals(s)) {
            arrayListCount.set(count , arrayListCount.get(count) + 1);
       }                
    }
    count++;
}
// Code for getting count ends here

arrayList.clear();
arrayList.addAll(set);
```

**Note:** The sequence of the `List` won't be retained.

Hope that Helps!!!

Comment: but how can i keep track of how many times a particular string repeats?

Comment: @ChromeLandos Sorry, I missed out on that part, but I have made an edit to the answer. But still I would recommend you to use `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for filtering you CustomList based on a particular String of the list. If you want to count the number of occurence, you can add some counter in the loop.

```
List<MyCustomObject> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
List<MyCustomObject> result = new ArrayList<>();

Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
for(MyCustomObject item : arrayList) {
   if(set.add(item.getSomeString()) {
       resultArray.add(item);
   }
}
arrayList.clear();
arrayList.addAll(result);
```